# Event firing but listener's are not being called

Tags: php, laravel

I have an event called EmailReceived which fires when one of my routes is hit by Mailgun, i have a listener called ProcessEmail, which parses out some information from the email, this part works fine.

I created another route to reprocess an email with a single line to fire the event, and the listener is not being called.

I have added logging to each event so i can see what is being hit and what is not.

```php
// From my EventService Provider

protected $listen = [
   EmailReceived::class => [
      ProcessEmail::class
   ],
];

// My processEmail listener
public function handle(EmailReceived $event)
{
   Log::info("Handling event ProcessEmail");
}

// My routes file
Route::get('incomingEmail/{email}/reprocess', 'InboundEmailController@reprocess');
Route::post('incomingEmail', 'InboundEmailController@receive');

// My controller methods
public function receive()
{
    $e = new InboundEmail;
    Log::info(request()->all());
    $e->content = request()->all();
    $e->save();

    Log::info("Firing event EmailReceived from receive");
    event(new EmailReceived($e));
}

public function reprocess(InboundEmail $e)
{
    Log::info("Firing Event EmailReceived from reprocess");
    event(new EmailReceived($e));
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: In your `EventServiceProvider.php`, what do your use statments look like for `EmailReceived` and `ProcessEmail`? Are you log messages in both `receive()` and `reprocess()` running?

Comment: would you believe i just solved it. I resolved using telescope, both were firing the event, the listeners were getting called but they are all getting queued, and because i have no worker running, it's not processing the queue

Answer (score 0):

Upon further investigation using telescope, i could see that my event was being fired for both methods, but my listener was not running for either method, some other logging confused me into thinking it was running.

My listeners were getting queued, and i have no worker running.